# YouTrack - Close Time Tracking after period

Tags: youtrack, time-tracking

Is it possible to allow time tracking entries or changes only up to a specified selected period in YouTrack?
Example: It is only allowed to make entries and changes for the last week. If you want to edit entries with a date 14 days ago, that is only possible for admins.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing a custom workflow that would check whether the creator of the work item or its updater belongs to a certain group (an admin group, for example).

Here you can find the YouTrack Workflow reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/youtrack-workflow-reference.html

The YT Workflow API reference is here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/YouTrack-Api-Documentation.html